# Jump page with animation - menu to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firstly, sorry for my bad english, I'm not a english native speaker.
Secondly, I'm really starting in Jquery and I am searching a lot for it in many forums.

So...

I have a html, css and JS file.

So, I am trying to do this:
When I click in a anchor, animate (jump) to a div.

I'm trying this code:

```
$(#lnkInicio).click(function() {
         $('html, body').animate({
           'scrollTop':   $('#perfil').offset().top
         }, 2000);
    });
```

But it doesn't works.

## testeBotao is my anchor id.

## perfil is my div id.

Look this:
When I use this one it works, but when page is created:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
       'scrollTop':   $('#perfil').offset().top
     }, 2000);
});
```

I wanna put it on anchor click "event".

What do I am doing wrong?

Just to simplify, here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title> Teste - Menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header-principal">
    <h1 id="titulo"> My page </h1>
        
   <nav id="menu">
   <ul>
       <li><a id="lnkInicio" href='#'>Início</a></li>
       <li><a id="lnkPerfil" href='#perfil'>Perfil</a></li>
       <li><a id="lnkMatricula" href='#'>Matrícula</a></li>
       <li><a id="lnkBoletim" href='#'>Boletim</a></li>
   </ul>
   </nav>
    </header>
    
    <div id="inicio"> 
    <p> some text here or elements </p>
    </div>
    <div id="perfil">
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    <p> I wanna to jump here :/ </p>
    
    </div>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotations around your selector `#lnkInicio`:

```
$('#lnkInicio').click(function(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault(); //to prevent from appending hash to url
     $('html, body').animate({
       'scrollTop':   $('#perfil').offset().top
     }, 2000);
});
```